# For loop to print consecutive numbers?

Tags: java, for-loop

I am supposed to build a code that asks for the users name, asks for a number between one and ten until I get number within that range, and then prints the numbers from 1 to the number the user entered except every third number should be the user's name that was entered at the beginning of the program. For example if the number was 4 and the name is Tom the output will be:

```
  1
  2
  Tom
  4
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to do the third part. I would prefer to use a for loop. Can someone explain how I could do this?
Here's what (little) I have so far.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

/**
 *
 * @author Home
 */
public class NewClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

        System.out.print( "Enter your name: ");
        String name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.print( "Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        number = scan.nextInt();

        while ( number >= 1 && number <= 10)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
System.out.print( "Enter your name: ");
String name = scan.nextLine();

System.out.print( "Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
int number = scan.nextInt();

//asks for a number between one and ten until I get number within that range,
while (number < 1 || number > 10) {
    System.out.print( "No, between 1 and 10: ");
    number = scan.nextInt();
}


for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
    if (i % 3 == 0) {
        System.out.print(name + " ");
    } else {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Enter your name: Tom
Please enter a number between 1 and 10: 21
No, between 1 and 10: 7
1 2 Tom 4 5 Tom 7
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not to difficult to achieve with the modulus operator `%` and a for loop. The `%` sign basically gives the remainder of a division. So for instance `12%3` is 0 and `13%3` is 1.

```
for(int i = 1; i < number ; i++ ){
  if(i%3 == 0) // This is the modulus operator, it gives the remainder
  {
     System.out.print(name);
  } else {
     System.out.print(i);
  }
}
```

To check if the input is 10 than ten you can use an if else statement before this. Or you could wrap your input in a loop till the user gives the correct answer:

```
while (number < 1 || number > 10) {
    System.out.print( "Only accept numbers between 1-10");
    number = scan.nextInt();
}
```

Although it'd lead to an infinite loops. You might wnt to give the user a limited number of tries.

Comment: *asks for a number between one and ten until I get number within that range,* - needs a loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat Don't you see a for loop in the code ?

Comment: @Steephen Not sure where your comment is directed.  When I made my comment there was no loop coded

Answer (score 0):

```
    Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);

    System.out.print( "Enter your name: ");
    String name = scan.nextLine();

    System.out.print( "Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
    int number = scan.nextInt();

    while (number < 1 || number > 10) {
        System.out.print( "Please enter a number between 1 and 10: ");
        number = scan.nextInt();
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
        if (i % 3 == 0) {
            System.out.print(name + " ");
        } else {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Beware the infinite loop